# Google Sheets conditional formatting cell color on value in cell AND presense of text in separate cell

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

As the title suggests, I'm trying to figure out how to format cells in the spreadsheet to be filled by a specific color based on if they have a value in them (negative or positive) AND depending on what specific word is in a particular column. If there's no value in the cell, there would be no fill.

Example: Column A cells have various words in it (all of the cells with at least two words) but I'm focused on the specific words "Penalty" and "Rewards". Column C through L have varying dollar amounts (some positive, some negative) and many of the cells are blank. I'd like the cells with values in them (C:L) to match the color of the corresponding word cells (A) based off of the words (Penalty/Reward).

This is what I'm trying to make it look like...

[image: DesiredSpreadsheet]

I attempted to find the answer elsewhere, but couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

see:

```
=COUNTIF($A1, "*reward*")*(A1<>"")
```

---

```
=COUNTIF($A1, "*penalty*")*(A1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: That was brilliant, thank you! Worked perfectly.